# Error in R t_test , not enough "x" observations

Tags: r, t-test, groupwise

I am trying to conduct group-wise t-test , but the code i am using returnign an error. It has worked alright for me previously and on other data frame but for this data frame its giving this error

> Error in t.test.default(x = 0.0268, y = 0.0223, paired = FALSE,
> var.equal = FALSE,  :    not enough 'x' observations

My Code is

```
stat.test.BACI5 <- Flaov %>%
  group_by(`Treatment`) %>%
  t_test(`Observed` ~  Control,  detailed = TRUE) %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni") %>%
  add_significance()
```

Here is the data structure

```
structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Phase1", "Phase2"), class = "factor"), Group = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Group A ", "Group B", "Group C ", 
"Group D"), class = "factor"), Observed = c(0.1057, 0.151, 0.0576, 
0.1267, 0.0941, 0.1554, 0.0247, 0.0832, 0.2807, 0.1137, 0.0325, 
0.0777, 0.0362, 0.0637, 0.0303, 0.0223, 0.0932, 0.0363, 0.0641, 
0.0453, 0.0359, 0.0334, 0.2006, 0.0538, 0.1114, 0.0661, 0.2452, 
0.1043, 0.0489, 0.0663, 0.1967, 0.0321, 0.1042, 0.0268, 0.0313, 
0.0255, 0.0787, 0.038, 0.1212, 0.0839, 0.0446, 0.0986, 0.1364, 
0.0335, 0.0409, 0.0407, 0.0871, 0.0584, 0.0875, 0.1961, 0.0711, 
0.0191, 0.0363, 0.0474, 0.1608, 0.0349, 0.1099, 0.0399, 0.1095, 
0.2011, 0.057, 0.0418, 0.0394, 0.054, 0.2033, 0.0631, 0.1089, 
0.0441, 0.0261, 0.0686), Control = c(0.1061, 0.154, 0.0585, 0.1289, 
0.1076, 0.15856, 0.02997, 0.1022, 0.2849, 0.1193, 0.03292, 0.0888, 
0.04628, 0.06454, 0.03341, 0.0239, 0.1013, 0.0364, 0.0883, 0.06363, 
0.0566, 0.04036, 0.20641, 0.06206, 0.1158, 0.0687, 0.2457, 0.12643, 
0.05126, 0.05705, 0.1987, 0.04719, 0.08199, 0.02312, 0.0317, 
0.07045, 0.06395, 0.06043, 0.1251, 0.0912, 0.04575, 0.1018, 0.1379, 
0.03834, 0.048, 0.04131, 0.0926, 0.06242, 0.0965, 0.1972, 0.0742, 
0.0211, 0.04318, 0.05741, 0.1616, 0.06552, 0.1104, 0.04814, 0.11015, 
0.2081, 0.06341, 0.04329, 0.04486, 0.06179, 0.2114, 0.05545, 
0.1127, 0.04327, 0.03355, 0.07189), factors = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Phase1", "Phase2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
70L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please add some data here  you can use `dput(dframe)`

Comment: Treatment       Group       Observed          Control          factors  
 Phase1:46   Group A :28   Min.   :0.01910   Min.   :0.02110   Phase1:46  
 Phase2:24   Group B :21   1st Qu.:0.03835   1st Qu.:0.04651   Phase2:24  
             Group C :11   Median :0.06390   Median :0.06503              
             Group D :10   Mean   :0.08227   Mean   :0.08796              
                           3rd Qu.:0.10810   3rd Qu.:0.11034              
                           Max.   :0.28070   Max.   :0.28490

Comment: Rather edit the question with the results of the `dput()` function that will show the specific structure of the data.frame that returns the error as suggested by @PKumar. Without data, I expect that the data.frame was subset in a way that reduced the number of levels. Try `droplevels()`, when subsetting the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a t test between observed and control in the different treatment groups, the formula is wrong, the left hand side of the formula should be the response variable and right hand side should be grouping variable.

In your case, you need to pivot the data long to get something like this:

```
library(tidyr)
Flaov[,c("Treatment","Observed","Control")] %>% 
pivot_longer(-c(Treatment)) %>% group_by(Treatment)
# A tibble: 140 x 3
# Groups:   Treatment [2]
   Treatment name      value
   <fct>     <chr>     <dbl>
 1 Phase1    Observed 0.106 
 2 Phase1    Control  0.106 
 3 Phase1    Observed 0.151 
 4 Phase1    Control  0.154 
 5 Phase1    Observed 0.0576
 6 Phase1    Control  0.0585
 7 Phase1    Observed 0.127 
 8 Phase1    Control  0.129 
 9 Phase1    Observed 0.0941
10 Phase1    Control  0.108 
# … with 130 more rows
```

Then we further pipe it to test:

```
Flaov[,c("Treatment","Observed","Control")] %>% 
pivot_longer(-c(Treatment)) %>% 
group_by(Treatment) %>% 
t_test(value ~ name)

# A tibble: 2 x 9
  Treatment .y.   group1  group2      n1    n2 statistic    df     p
* <fct>     <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Phase1    value Control Observed    46    46     0.482  90.0 0.631
2 Phase2    value Control Observed    24    24     0.323  46.0 0.748
```

Comment: It works , But still dont understand that why the previous did not worked, i have another data frame in eactly the same format as the previous one , and it worked

Comment: thats the way you use formulas in R. no idea why it worked in your magical previous example. check if results are correct